# How to retain order of JSON data retrieved with AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I am using `AFNetworking` to retrieve JSON data from a web service.  Part of the response string I get is:

```
{"DATA":{"LEASE TYPE":"3 Yrs + 0 renew of 0 Yrs","LANDLORD":"","TENANT":"test comp"...
```

and so on.  The order of the key values in the "DATA" dictionary ("LEASE TYPE","LANDLORD","TENANT"...) is important for presentation purposes.  However, when `AFNetworking` calls `NSJSONSerialization's`:

```
+ (id)JSONObjectWithData:(NSData *)data options:(NSJSONReadingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error;
```

method, the returned dictionary has the keys in a different order.

I notice that the `AFJSONRequestOperation` object has the server's response stored as an `NSString`, with everything in the correct order.  However I'm not keen on parsing the JSON by hand if I can avoid it.

Can anyone suggest a way that will let me get at / keep the keys in their original order?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the order is important use an array not a dictionary, dictionaries are be by their nature unordered. Or add an array of dictionary keys in the order desired.

If you have no control over the response that is sent you will have to parse the JSON yourself at least for the ordering.

Comment: I think you're right - I have basically no control over the process that turns the text into a dictionary, so parsing the JSON a second time is effectively my only option.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you'r creating an NSDictionary, the order will not be the same. I often recognized that dictionaries get ordered by key-name alphabetically.

But when using dictionaries the order doesn't really matter. And they shouldn't!

Comment: I certainly appreciate that this is the way it should be in principle.  However in this case, the original order is important.  My question is not about what is correct behaviour, but about the best way to (re)capture the original order of the data as it is returned from the server.

Comment: As far as I know, dictionaries can't be ordered and they will not keep their order. I think the only way to achieve this is using two arrays. You can then get the value using `[values objectAtIndex:[keys indexOfObject:@"myKey"]]`

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answers mentions dictionaries are by nature without order, but you can find here a nice class of **OrderedDictionary**:

http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/ordereddictionary-subclassing-cocoa.html

http://projectswithlove.com/projects/OrderedDictionary.zip