# Decode KeyValuePairs<String: Person> from JSON

Tags: ios, swift, decodable

I have a JSON response that looks something like this:

```
 {
    "persons": {
        "John": {
            "name": "John",
            "age": 24
        },
        "Michael": {
            "name": "Michael",
            "age": 44
        },
        "Jack": {
            "name": "Jack",
            "age": 25
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this could be parse with a struct that looks like this:

```
struct PersonsResponse: Decodable {
    let persons: [String: Person]
}

struct Person: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let age: Ing
}
```

However, what this does, is returns a dictionary and parses fine. What I would need is to preserve the order of the persons as they arrive inside this JSON response. I have come across `KeyValuePairs` in swift which basically are ordered dictionaries but for the love of God I can't figure out how to decode it into being an `KeyValuePairs<String, Person>`.

Apple documentation says that instantiating a `KeyValuePairs` object is as easy as doing:

```
let recordTimes: KeyValuePairs = ["Florence Griffith-Joyner": 10.49,
                                      "Evelyn Ashford": 10.76,
                                      "Evelyn Ashford": 10.79,
                                      "Marlies Gohr": 10.81]
```

Literally. But when I am decoding my response with:

```
struct PersonsResponse: Decodable {
    let persons: KeyValuePairs<String, Person>
    ...
    ...

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    ...
    let personsDictionary = try container.decode([String: Person].self, forKey: .persons)
```

and then try to do:

```
    persons = personsDictionary
```

of course it doesn't work at all. I tried to do all kinds of magic already with no luck. Does anyone have any solution to parsing dictionaries into ordered sequences or even Arrays? Thanks for helping!

There is NO WAY the JSON response changes into being an array and YES it always is the same order.

Comment: `KeyValuePairs` is not related to `CodingKeys` at all. A dictionary is an unordered collection type. Are you sure the dictionaries in the JSON are sent always in the same order? If you are responsible for the backend, send an array.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you have any ability to change that JSON format, you should. If you have two people with the same name, you won't be able to include both in the results.

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate, but the underlying problem is identical, and the answer is identical. You cannot do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081104/how-to-retain-order-of-json-data-retrieved-with-afnetworking?rq=1  JSONDecoder currently puts all the data into an NSDictionary and then parses it out (since JSONDecoder is currently implemented on top of NSJSONSerialization). That step loses the order. You can't fix this using JSONDecoder (and I'm not aware of any off-the-shelf JSON parser in Swift that can).

Answer (score 0):

Both Swift, JSON Dictionaries are `unordered` by there nature. The JSON format does notmaintain key ordering, and as such, does not required parser to preserve the order.

If you need an ordered collection, you its better to returning an array of key-value pairs in the JSON

```
 {
    "persons": [
        { "John": {
            "name": "John",
            "age": 24
          }
        },
        {"Michael": {
            "name": "Michael",
            "age": 44
          }
        },
       { "Jack": {
            "name": "Jack",
            "age": 25
         }
       }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It's unclear why this is downvoted. This is the entire answer. JSON Dictionaries are not ordered, and cannot be decoded as though they were in Swift using the standard tools (you'd have to build something from scratch).

Comment: I'd just remove the outer name. You have an array of dictionaries, each containing one dictionary. You might just as well put all the dictionaries into an array.

Comment: @RobNapier But that’s not what the answer says. It says “make something different be emitted by the server”. That’s no answer.

Comment: I can't change the response. Just need to parse it